# Sql Server 2008 : Cannot define foreign key constraint with cascaded DELETE or UPDATE

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, foreign-keys

When trying to apply the `ON CASCADE UPDATE` or `ON CASCADE DELETE` for some foreign key, I get the following error :

> Msg 1787 : Cannot define foreign key constraint  with cascaded DELETE or
>   UPDATE on table because the table has an INSTEAD OF DELETE or
>   UPDATE TRIGGER defined on it.

here is my SQL code :

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ACTE__CODE_OBJET_ACTE] FOREIGN KEY ([My_Column] ) REFERENCES Table_Referenced ([Column_Referenced]) ON UPDATE CASCADE  ON DELETE CASCADE ;
```

What is the problem with my request ? Is CASCADE condition incompatible with instead of delete or update triggers ?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the problem with my request ? Is CASCADE condition
>   incompatible with instead of delete or update triggers ?

Yes. Please check

[Designing INSTEAD OF Triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

and

[Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> INSTEAD OF DELETE and INSTEAD OF UPDATE triggers cannot be defined on
>   a table that has a foreign key that is defined by using a DELETE or
>   UPDATE cascading action.

Also:

> Cascading actions cannot be specified for a table that has an INSTEAD
>   OF UPDATE or INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger. After a cascading action has
>   been defined for a table, an INSTEAD OF UPDATE or INSTEAD OF DELETE
>   trigger cannot be added to it.

You can use `AFTER triggers` instead if you are able to.

**EDIT**

You're actually contradicting yourself. You have to decide which logic you really want; the INSTEAD OF trigger that redirects the operation to some other logic or the cascade operation in the foreign key.

Comment: Yes I see the problem :) But how can I overcome it ?

Comment: Oh I see ! Is there a way to implement the CASCADE option programmatically in my triggers ??

Comment: sure. kindly check this out: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/sqlguru/q061400-1.shtml